# Using thermal expansion to "passively" realign solar panels

Tags: thermal-expansion

Can one use thermal expansion to "passively" realign solar panels (whether they are used for photo voltaic production or direct heat production)?

**BACKGROUND**

The efficiency of [Solar panels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_panel) depends on their alignment with the sun's position in the sky.  Keeping this alignment is costly, whether done by hand or via an electronic device.  Could [thermal expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion) be used to transform heat in movement and automatically rotate a solar panel when slightly misaligned, and hence progressively adjusting the reflectors' position during a day of uninterrupted sun exposure?

I would like to study theoretically the potential of the thermal expansion of metal (e.g. [Aluminum, Linear coefficient 23.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion#General_thermal_expansion_coefficient)), Polymer (e.g. Polypropylene, 150) and liquids (Gasoline, 317) to generate enough movement to realign a set of reflectors **beyond a "clicker" threshold** (so that the solar panel does not move back once the material cools down), so that the material used for the thermal expansion can cool down and be used again at the next misalignment. And then, maybe, to validate such theoretical work using a small scale set of reflector illuminating a photovoltaic sensor, used to monitor the process of realignment with the sun during the day.

But the idea seems a bit too simple: if it worked, somebody would have done it already, and if nobody did it, it could be because one can easily demonstrate that the forces produced by thermal expansion are insufficient to generate sufficient movement. Yet searching for "solar panels realignment" did not yield any useful results, hence the question here, in order to avoid "reinventing the wheel"...

Comment: The Home Power magazine covered many methods of aligning panels - two of the simplest: one involved water being dripped into a counterweight and emptied at the end of the day, the other was a lens with two small (3") panels at 90 degrees driving a small dc motor. As the lens put more light on one panel cf the other the motor would turn...

Comment: This seems possible in principle.  The main question is whether it could be implememted in a way that's cheaper than simply using a motor to realign. If the motor itself were solar powered, it seems to me the motor is a cheaper and easier option. But I haven't run any numbers on the benefit of good alignment vs the cost to install and run the motor.

Comment: You question made me think of older thermostats, that would use thermal expansion of a coil of dissimilar metals, or sometimes a vial of mercury, to act as a temperature-controlled switch

Comment: [Explored by team Heliotrope in a 2008 MIT engineering competition](https://news.mit.edu/2008/madmec-0919).

Comment: SMA is the obvious metallic solution. AKA memory metal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape-memory_alloy

Comment: @RC_23 I really like the idea of the vial of mercury, I will search for references: thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bingo. Exactly what you need here.

https://youtube.com/shorts/CQ3bv7mbRBE

Just be sure to give that guy intellectual credit if you are doing anything official with it.

Comment: Excellent! I thought of that solution (but did not know the project, so a billion thanks for the pointer to the video!), but I am afraid that solar panels might STILL be too high-tech for a "sustainable future" (in the sense that we need to extract many different metals to build them, and do not (yet) know how to do so without fossil fuels): I want to explore the possibility and cost of a thermal expansion based solution. BUT I will definitely cite this guy as "state of the art", thanks a lot!